# Combine find/filter function in jQuery while locating DOM elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom, frontend, getelementbyid

I want to find all elements inside #Grid, then inside a first "TR" tag they should have attribute role="row" and attribute role="columnheader". 
I've got it and it works fine. 
Example:

```
var elements = $("#Grid").find("tr").attr("role","row").first().find("th").attr("role", "columnheader");
```

What I want to do is to filter it only to elements which meet the condition: offsetWidth < scrollWidth

I tried like below, but this is the incorrect result:

```
var elements = $("#Grid").find("tr").attr("role", "row").first().find("th").attr("role", "columnheader");
var filtered = elements.filter(function () {
    return $(this).offsetWidth < $(this).scrollWidth;
});
```

I can use this function as well, but I don't really know how to combine it in jQuery:

```
function isEllipsisActive(e) {
    return (e.offsetWidth < e.scrollWidth);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Should work:

```
var filtered = elements.filter(function () {
    return this.offsetWidth < this.scrollWidth;
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Don't use $(this), use the element variable existing in the filter function.

```
var filtered = elements.toArray().filter(function (e) {
    return e.offsetWidth < e.scrollWidth;
});
```

Comment: While this code snippet may be the solution, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-‌​code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.